# Keycloak API throws CORS errors for some reuqests only

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I'm using localhost to develop an application using Keycloak for managing users. * is set for Valid redirect URIs and web origins.

```
POST /{realm}/users
const userCreateResp = await fetchJson(`${CONSTANTS.KEYCLOAK_API_URL}/realms/${CONSTANTS.KEYCLOAK_REALM_NAME}/users`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'authorization': `Bearer ${session['accessToken']}`,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        firstName: firstName,
        lastName: lastName,
        email: email,
        username: username,
        emailVerified: true,
        enabled: true,
        attributes: { dealer: session.user.username },
        credentials: [{ type: 'password', value: password, temporary: false }]
    })
});
```

Then I try to make a different call to `GET /{realm}/groups/{id}/role-mappings/clients/{client}/available` but the request is blocked by CORS on chrome: https://i.imgur.com/M3irGE3.png

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you successfully fetch the response and extract the token. could you post the config page about the your current realm's client

Comment: @smileis2333 https://imgur.com/WItco3k should I post anything else? I tried with + or * but without success

Comment: i try to reproduce your case but i fail, all run correctly ,i use keycloak-20.0.5. could you export the realm config and provider the specific version of keycloak.

Comment: @smileis2333 there you go mate https://pastebin.com/1HnVLDwW version 20.0.2 run from a docker container

Comment: i import your realm config, and create the account service-account-otg2(because i change the existed account credential but fail), the assign this account the internal role. then i create test.html put two button, one for fetch the token,the second access the `GET /{realm}/groups/{id}/role-mappings/clients/{client}/available`. When not config "Web origins" in the admin-cli, there occure cors problem, after config 'Web origins: *', the cors be solved.  my host environment is windows10. Any difference between my operation and your operation? i  can post the operation in the answer if you need it

Comment: nevermind it turned out I forgot to add `/realms/` to the endpoint url: `GET: http://localhost:8080/admin/realms/{realm}/users/{userId}/role-mappings/realm/available`. This documentation is so confusing OMG